# Need advice on using a DC motor to generate mechanical drag for an exercise "sled"

Tags: dc-motor

I'm trying to DIY-emulate an existing, but pretty expensive, piece of exercise equipment. Though called a "sled," it's really just a cart that provides resistance as you push it down the street. In the commercial version, one of the wheels is connected by chain-and-sprockets to what appears to be the kind of brushed DC motor that's usually used to power an electric scooter. The motor isn't connected to any electricity, and instead the idea is to have *you* drive the motor, which creates mechanical drag by resisting and absorbing your motion. This in turn it converts into electricity -- which I suppose then just gets burned off as heat. I'm looking for advice on speccing and wiring the motor.

1. Power
   Analysis of a video of this thing in action suggests that the motor absorbs roughly 600 watts (150 kg at 2 m/s down a 20% slope -- yeah for freshman physics!). Actually, the manufacturer claims that, the faster you move the thing -- higher RPMs -- the harder you have to push. I'm trying to figure what the right power rating should be. For example, would a motor rated at 2000 or 3000 watts be too difficult to move in the first place? Or would it simply absorb whatever power you produce, just with a higher overall absorptive capacity? Or would it get too hard too fast, so that a wattage in the zone of 500 or 1000 would be preferable?
2. Wiring
   There really aren't any controls on this thing -- if you're not pushing, the motor does nothing. I just wonder how the power is burned off. It *looks* like they've simply shorted the leads of the motor -- can it be that simple? Or must there be some big resistor there that I'm not seeing? In the final analysis, the energy from your pushing just heats stuff up -- but that has to be something that can be reasonably cooled. (Incidentally, I'm also wondering how the voltage rating affects this power dissipation). Any thoughts on how this can be handled?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Mechanical considerations aside, what you're wanting to do is basically short-circuit the motor.   This is called 'Dynamic Braking' and is common.  To get maximum resistance you'd connect the motor terminals with a dead short wire...to get variable loads you can put resistors of different values across the motor instead of a dead short.

The resistors "probably" would be like 1 to 10 ohms, and of high power (many dozens if not 100's of watts).   Alternately a high power rheostat can be used as a variable resistor.

My numbers are swags...  how are you in physics?  I.e. do we have to calculate the power involved or can you figure it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

A [human being in average physical condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_power) can produce about 100-200 watts continuously, and 200-500 watts for a few minutes. So a permanent magnet brushed motor of similar size should be sufficient. There should not be much difference in effort for a 200 watt (1/4 HP) or a 2000 watt (2.5 HP) motor loaded to produce the same wattage. There will be different combinations of torque and speed that produce the same power, so you might want to add variable gearing like a bicycle derailleur or [Sturmey-Archer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmey-Archer) hub to get different ratios depending if you want to push hard and slow, or easy and fast.

Instead of burning up the energy as heat, you might consider connecting the generator to a rechargeable battery through a [DC to DC charger](https://www.amazon.com/dc-battery-charger/s?k=dc%20to%20dc%20battery%20charger). You should find one with a wide range of input voltages, and adjustable output current to adjust the power you want to put out. You might also add a [DC volt/amp/watt meter](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=dc%20volt%20amp%20watt%20meter&crid=1M2DRRRY71XJX&sprefix=dc%20volt%20amp%2Caps%2C106&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_5_11) so you can see how much power you are generating.